# syntax error on tokens, variableDeclarator expected instead

Tags: java, android, syntax

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
  cv.put(colDeptID, 1);
  cv.put(colDeptName, "Sales");
  db.insert(deptTable, colDeptID, cv);

  cv.put(colDeptID, 2);
  cv.put(colDeptName, "IT");
  db.insert(deptTable, colDeptID, cv);
                    db.close();
```

With this code, I am getting a red underline under the parenthesis after put in every line and getting this error:
Syntax error on token "(", delete this token.

I also get an error that says:
Syntax error on tokens, variableDeclarator expected instead.  Any ideas?  I've tried everything I know to do, and none of it worked.

Edit:
I also get 
Syntax error on "close", identifier expected after this token

I copy and pasted this code from a tutorial and all the comments said it worked, but I've had quite a few problems out of it.  Thanks for such quick replies.

Comment: Try going to Project -> Clean

Comment: Is this code inside a method or constructor?

Comment: Clean didn't work, and no, it's not.  It's just in the class.

Comment: @HollisScriber : that's why it's not working move it inside an method and  call that method for inserting record

Comment: @HollisScriber : plz share tutorial link where you find this code

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/119293/Using-SQLite-Database-with-Android

Comment: @HollisScriber : well your problem get solved but link is not working on my side

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan could you add your solution as an answer so Hollis can accept it please?

Comment: @ataulm Done. I've expanded it with some explanation.

Answer (score 7):

Only declarations, such as:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
```

can be directly inside a class declaration. Non-declarations, such as:

```
  cv.put(colDeptID, 1);
  cv.put(colDeptName, "Sales");
  db.insert(deptTable, colDeptID, cv);
```

must be inside a method, constructor, initializer block, or static initializer block. In this case they should probably be in a constructor or method.

Answer (score 0):

By Variable Declarator ID, it means something like **int** or **string**. Example: `int randomnum = 9` or something like that.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Put the code inside a method and not directly inside the class.

Like

```
SomeRandomMethod(){
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
  cv.put(colDeptID, 1);
  cv.put(colDeptName, "Sales");
  db.insert(deptTable, colDeptID, cv);

  cv.put(colDeptID, 2);
  cv.put(colDeptName, "IT");
  db.insert(deptTable, colDeptID, cv);
                    db.close();
}
```